# how is the minus sign understood in set theory, is it similar to the complement (\) function.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

Assume:
$A = \{1,2,3\},$
$B = \{2,3,4\}$

Is $A - B = \{1\}$, or is it $\{1\}$ plus the piece of $\{4\}$ that you 'owe', assuming in Venn Diagram you are subtracting a piece of $B$ from $A$ itself that do not contain the element '4'. (Is it fair to visualise sets in Venn Diagrams?)

Or do we just equate the minus($-$) sign to the complement() function.

Comment: Note that $A - B = A \cap B^c$, so in your example $A-B = \{ 1 \}$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The symbols $-$ and $\setminus$ typically denote the same thing, namely *relative complement* (a.k.a. *set difference*):
$$A - B = A \setminus B = \{ x \mid x \in A \text{ and } x \not \in B \}$$
The other operation you mention is *symmetric difference*, often denoted $A \triangle B$, which is defined by
$$A \triangle B = (A \setminus B) \cup (B \setminus A)$$
or equivalently $A \triangle B = (A \cup B) \setminus (A \cap B)$; it is the set of objects which are elements exactly one of $A$ or $B$.

In your case, you have $\{ 1, 2, 3 \} \setminus \{ 2, 3, 4 \} = \{ 1 \}$ and $\{ 1, 2, 3 \} \triangle \{ 2, 3, 4 \} = \{ 1, 4 \}$.

Answer (score 5):

$A-B$ is alternative notation for $A \setminus B$. They both mean the elements that are in $A$ but not in $B$.

Answer (score -3):

I'm sorry.

I truly am.

Usually[1], the symbol $A - B$ means $A\setminus B= \{x\in A| x\not \in B\}= A\cap B^c$.

(In your example $\{1,2,3\}-\{2,3,4\} =\{1\}$.)

*Except* sometimes it means $A- B = \{a-b|a\in A; b \in B\}$ (where is assumed $A$ and $B$ are sets of numbers.)

(In which case $\{1,2,3\}-\{2,3,4\} =\{-3,-2,-1,0,1\}$.)

Which one does your *text* mean?  Well, you can tell in context if it is well-written.

Again.  Accept my deepest condolences and sympathy.

====

[1] By "usually" I mean, that when you *do* see it, it usually means this.  Fortunately you won't see it that often as most texts recognize its ambiguity and use $A\setminus B$ instead.

But, unfortunately, one does sometimes sees it.  Really, I can't tell you how sorry I am about this.